# Reasons to not use 'break' statement in loops

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I'm testing [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/) in order to check the quality of my code.

In a loop, I have something like that :

```
foreach(var someVar in someList)
{
    if(condition)
        //Do stuff
    else
        break;
}
```

SonarQube tells me :

> Refactor the code in order to remove this break statement.

I can do it by constructing a list which respects my condition, but can someone explain why using `break` is considered as a bad practice ?

Comment: I use it all the time to avoid crowding my loop conditions and to avoid having to scope variables involved in the decision to outside of the loop. I'd also love to know why this is considered bad practice.

Comment: Any reason not to use `TakeWhile`? That would be simpler, IMO: `foreach (var someVar in someList.TakeWhile(condition))`

Comment: @JonSkeet - nice! Didn't know about this.

Comment: In this particular case filtering the source before iterating would give clearer code. But "don't use `break`" in general is silly.

Comment: I'd go as far as `if (!condition) { break; }` then `//Dostuff`, which makes the break nice and obvious at the top of your loop.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that ReSharper tends to suggest the opposite - use breaks to avoid nesting. I just judge whether it makes the code more readable on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I fed that exact message to Google and it turned up [this](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARCS-263). It says: *"The `break;` statement, as its name indicates, breaks the control flow of the program in an unstructured way. It reduces the program readability, and makes refactoring more complex when used outside of `switch`."* Can't exactly say I agree, and I'm not even sure if it's an official opinion, but it found its way into SonarQube anyway so there you go.

Comment: @JonSkeet No particular reason. I like your solution ; in my case, I used something like this : `var list = someUIElement.ChildrenOfType<...>().Where(condition);`, but I think it's the same. I only wanted to know if they were other reasons that *clarity* of code for not using `break`.

Comment: @Chostakovitch `Where` is *not* the same as `TakeWhile`. `Where` gets *all* the elements that match the predicate; `TakeWhile` only gets the elements that match *until the first element that doesn't match*. In other words, `While` is like replacing your `break` with a `continue`.